# zip code validation in as2

Tags: actionscript-2, zipcode

I'm trying to validate zip code entries in an input text box. So far I was able to have it return true if 5 digits are entered. But in some cases where an invalid zip like 00000 is entered, it still acts like a valid zipcode was entered. Right now I have:

```
if(zipEntered == false)
    {

    }
    else
    {   
        if(input_mc.input_txt.length == 5)
        {
            trace("valid zip");
        }

        else {
            trace("not valid zip");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [this list](http://www.phaster.com/zip_code.html) to determine what ranges of zip codes are valid, and then amend your code:

```
var numericZip = parseInt(input_mc.input_txt.text);
var zipValid = (
  (numericZip >= 35801 && numericZip <= 35816) /* Alabama */
  || (numericZip >= 99501 && numericZip <= 99524) /* Alaska */
  // etc
```